# I Obtain the error "Path must be a string"

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have two classes in the same folder called controllers.js and utile.js. Utile.js is a class of client utily. This is utile.js:

```
'use strict';

define('utile', [], function() {
    var modulo = {};

modulo.getLimiteCaratterePost = function() {
        var limite_carattari_post = 25;
        return limite_carattari_post;
    };
return modulo;
});
```

in my controllers.js I need to use this method, so I try import this class in this way:

```
async.waterfall([
            function(next){
                //the error start from the above line
                require(['utile'], function (utile) { 
                    console.log("uitle dentro "+JSON.stringify(utile_metodo.getLimiteCaratterePost()));
                    return next();
                 });

            },
            function(next) {
                console.log("GET LIMITE CARATTER "+JSON.stringify(utile_metodo.getLimiteCaratterePost()));
                db.getObject(hash + ":bookmark:" + id_bookmark, next);
            },
...... (continue the problem is the import);
```

The program gives it me :

```
/bookmark/5/aaa
 AssertionError: path must be a string
    at Module.require (module.js:496:3)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /vagrant/nodebb/node_modules/nodebb-plugin-connect-bookmarked/lib/controllers.js:34:5
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you paste your require.config main file?

Comment: @ayxos require.config({
 baseUrl: config.relative_path + "/src/modules",
 waitSeconds: 7,
 urlArgs: "v=" + config['cache-buster'],
 paths: {
  'forum': '../client',
  'admin': '../admin',
  'vendor': '../../vendor',
  'plugins': '../../plugins'
 }
});

Comment: My folder is not in the "baseUrl" path! How can I modify this?

Comment: what if you move that module as a subfolder of your baseUrl?

Answer (score 0):

At first, when you create module you have to export it using `module.exports` object by adding your method or object to it. For example`module.exports= {method: myMethod}` and so on

Then if you want to use module, you have to require it using `require(path)` where path can be a relative path, and must be a string. So if you want require module, you can use for exapmle `var utile = require('./utile.js')`

Comment: If I corret my code with your solution when in the controllers.js called  the method : "utile_metodo=require('./utile.js');
    console.log("PATH "+utile_metodo.getLimiteCaratterePost()); " I otbain the error:" define is not defined " in utile.js

Comment: Try export module, by adding to `module.exports` your object.

Comment: it give me "the module is not define" the problem is that this utile.js has some methods that I use from the client side. But I need to use some methods in controllers.js that is in the same folder. In the client file I do "require(['utile'], function(utile) {}" and it works but when I do in my controllers.js that is not a client file it's not work!

Comment: When you create module, you can just add function to the 'module.exports' object. Then in controllers.js, require your module at beginning and then use methods in async.waterfall function. After that, all methods stored in module should be available in controller.js file